# Infinite while loop involving boolean variable in Java

Tags: java, while-loop, boolean, infinite-loop

this is my first post, so apologies if I fail to follow proper formats/conventions etc. on this site. I've only been programming for a few weeks.

Anyways, I am writing a basic Java program using a boolean variable and a while loop. The code is very 'clunky' to say the least and could definitely be made much more elegant (though not with my limited skill set, so again, apologies). **If the boolean variable is true, the code works as it should. However, if the variable is false, the code goes to a while loop and even if an input is put in which should make the statement true, the loop just keeps going.** Any ideas what's causing this infinite loop. I'm practically certain it's something basic, but I just can't seem to figure it out. Here is the code below. Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import static java.lang.System.out;
import static java.lang.System.in;

public class MB1 {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        char a, b, c, d;
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(in);
        boolean secondBoolean;

        out.println("Let's get started! Type in your 4-digit code:");
        a = myScanner.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);
        b = myScanner.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);
        c = myScanner.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);
        d = myScanner.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);

        secondBoolean = ((a == '1'|| a == '2'|| a == '3' || a == '4' || a == '5' || a == '6' || a == '7')
            && (b == '1' || b == '2'|| b == '3' || b == '4' || b == '5' || b == '6' || b == '7')
            && (c == '1' || c == '2'|| c == '3' || c == '4' || c == '5' || c == '6' || c == '7')
            && (d == '1' || d == '2'|| d == '3' || d == '4' || d == '5' || d == '6' || d == '7'));

            while (secondBoolean == false) {
            out.println("The code you typed is not valid. Please type a different code:");
            a = myScanner.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);
            b = myScanner.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);
            c = myScanner.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);
            d = myScanner.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);  
            out.print(a);out.print(b);out.print(c);out.print(d);
            } 
            if (secondBoolean == true){
                out.println('0');
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Side note: that boolean expression is really ugly and hard to read. I would change it to `secondBoolean = a >= '1' && a <= '7' || b >= '1' && b <= '7' || c >= '1' && c <= '7' || d >= '1' && d <= '7'`

Comment: The indentation of your code is off.

Comment: There are already enough answers to your infinite loop problem, I just could suggest to use "do while" loop to reduce redundancy of your code (repeating the input and boolean assignment part)

Answer (score 1):

**Value of `secondBoolean` variable has to be recalculated each time.**

Replace

```
secondBoolean = ((a == '1'|| a == '2'|| a == '3' || a == '4' || a == '5' || a == '6' || a == '7')
        && (b == '1' || b == '2'|| b == '3' || b == '4' || b == '5' || b == '6' || b == '7')
        && (c == '1' || c == '2'|| c == '3' || c == '4' || c == '5' || c == '6' || c == '7')
        && (d == '1' || d == '2'|| d == '3' || d == '4' || d == '5' || d == '6' || d == '7'));

while (secondBoolean == false) {
    out.println("The code you typed is not valid. Please type a different code:");
    a = myScanner.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);
    b = myScanner.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);
    c = myScanner.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);
    d = myScanner.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);  
    out.print(a);out.print(b);out.print(c);out.print(d);
    } 
    if (secondBoolean == true){
        out.println('0');
    }
}
```

with

```
while (secondBoolean == false) {
    out.println("The code you typed is not valid. Please type a different code:");
    a = myScanner.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);
    b = myScanner.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);
    c = myScanner.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);
    d = myScanner.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0); 

    out.print(a);out.print(b);out.print(c);out.print(d);

    secondBoolean = ((a == '1'|| a == '2'|| a == '3' || a == '4' || a == '5' || a == '6' || a == '7')
        && (b == '1' || b == '2'|| b == '3' || b == '4' || b == '5' || b == '6' || b == '7')
        && (c == '1' || c == '2'|| c == '3' || c == '4' || c == '5' || c == '6' || c == '7')
        && (d == '1' || d == '2'|| d == '3' || d == '4' || d == '5' || d == '6' || d == '7'));
    } 
    if (secondBoolean == true){
        out.println('0');
    }
}
```

You should update value of `secondBoolean` in each iteration of the loop.

---

Additionally, you can improve your code's readability bye replacing it with

```
String choices = "1234567";
secondBoolean = choices.contains(a + "") && choices.contains(b + "")
             && choices.contains(c + "") && choices.contains(d + "");
```

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

You are in a infinite loop because you're *never* changing the value of `secondBoolean`. You should to this inside your while loop.

Also, don't forget to initialize you `secondBoolean` variable before the loop (setting `secondBoolean = false`, so your loop will run at least once).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to just read the user's input as a string and split it by "."

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import static java.lang.System.in;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class MB1 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        char a, b, c, d;
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(in);
        boolean secondBoolean;

        out.println("Let's get started! Type in your 4-digit code:");
        String strIn = myScanner.nextLine();

        // Split input by "."
        String[] strAry = strIn.split("\\.");

        // create char array of equal length to String array
        char[] chrAry = new char[strAry.length];

        // convert strings to chars
        for (int i = 0; i < strAry.length; i++) {
            chrAry[i] = strAry[i].charAt(0);
        }

        // (unnecessary) assignment to a, b, c and d
        a = chrAry[0];
        b = chrAry[1];
        c = chrAry[2];
        d = chrAry[3];

        secondBoolean = ((a == '1' || a == '2' || a == '3' || a == '4' || a == '5' || a == '6' || a == '7')
                && (b == '1' || b == '2' || b == '3' || b == '4' || b == '5' || b == '6' || b == '7')
                && (c == '1' || c == '2' || c == '3' || c == '4' || c == '5' || c == '6' || c == '7')
                && (d == '1' || d == '2' || d == '3' || d == '4' || d == '5' || d == '6' || d == '7'));

        while (!secondBoolean) {
            out.println("The code you typed is not valid. Please type a different code:");
            // ... read in code again. You possibly want to do this with a method
        }
        if (secondBoolean) {
            out.println('0');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you enter the loop when `secondBoolean` is false. 
You will go round and round in this loop until `secondBoolean` is set to true, therefore you must update this within the while loop.

On a side not, maybe your code could be tidied up a bit like this;

```
List<String> nums = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7");
secondBoolean=(nums.contains(a) && 
               nums.contains(b) && 
               nums.contains(c) && 
               nums.contains(d));
```

I am only starting java myself, but this looks a little neater! 
Hope that helped.